Private prayer in Aramaic language
The Gemara in Sota, quoted below, states that an individual prayer may not be said in Aramaic, but a collective prayer can be said in Aramaic.
Sota 33a.

THE 'PRAYER'. [It may be recited in any language because] it is only
supplication, and one may pray in any language he wishes. But may the
'prayer' be recited in any language? Behold Rab Judah has said: A man
should never pray for his needs in Aramaic. For R. Johanan declared:
If anyone prays for his needs in Aramaic, the Ministering Angels  do
not pay attention to him, because they do not understand that
language! — There is no contradiction, one referring to [the prayer]
of an individual and the other to that of a Congregation.

This rule is in SA OC 101 and discussed in comments.
See Mishna Berura s.q. 19:
ארמי ובצבור מותר אף לשון ארמי.

ובזה אתי שפיר מה דאומרים יקום פורקן ובריך שמיה בצבור וכדומה [פמ"ג].
ולפ"ז אם מתפלל בביתו אין יכול לאמר שום יקום פורקן. וכן מוכח באור זרוע
הגדול בהלכות שבת סי' נ

He says in name of the Peri Megadim that it's why we say Yoqum Purqan and Berich Shemeh in Aramaic in the congregation in synagogue.
But it's not clear what about someone who is in the congregation and want to pray a private prayer that others don't say.
E.g. at the end of Berich Shemeh, that is a private prayer in Nusach Sfard:

(וְתֵיהַב לִי בְּנִין דִּכְרִין דְּעָבְדִין רְעוּתָךְ,)

To ask male sons who make your will.
I'm wondering if it's fit to the rule stated in Gemara and Posqim.

There are many definitions of "praying with the minyan". One of them is that it means at the same time. It doesn't have to be in the same building.
